# EXE without Libraries / Runtimes?

Tags: dll, compiler-construction, installation, exe

I saw a software once that packed all the necessery runtimes + my exe file into one exe file. Then I can start the exe and it would start automatically (no runtimes installation)
For example i have an old vb6 exe file and other dlls / ocx ... + vb6 runtimes... I dont care If the exe will be then 5 MB. :)

I could do this with NSIS or other installer but is there something more elegant? (I know there is something like that! it was some commercial solution)

Thanks

Comment: DLLs are shared for good reasons. Be sure you understand the advantages before you throw them away.

Comment: It is very, very common and you already know it well.  The file is usually named setup.exe.  Not what you ask for, but custom linkers are usually very expensive, highly specific, hard to find and disliked by IT staff and users that cares about security.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [ThinApp](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/) (formerly Thinstall)?

> With VMware ThinApp, applications are
>   packaged into single executables that
>   run completely isolated from each
>   other and the operating system for
>   conflict-free execution on end-point
>   devices.

Answer (score 0):

May be smth like [Enigma Virtual Box](http://www.enigmaprotector.com/assets/files/enigmavb.exe/)?